# What is the regex for a "ui" string followed by a natural number/positiveinteger?

Tags: regex

Im trying to write a regex that accepts strings starting with ui and followed by any positive number. for instance: ui/1 ui/2 ui/3 ui/10 ui/2087.

^ui[W/][1-9]$ 
but this only works for ui/(1-9)
nothing greater than 9

i need it to work for any positive integer

Comment: Use `^ui\/[0-9]+$`. Why do you use `W`?

Comment: Is `ui/0045` valid?

Answer (score -1):

The answer depends on whether you want to allow leading zeroes. If not, it's just

```
^ui/[1-9][0-9]*$
```

If you want to allow leading zeroes, just add `0*` after the slash.

By the way, why do you allow `W` in addition to `/`?

Comment: Not sure who DV'd. This is correct given the info and examples provided. It would be nice if OP could provide the requested clarifications though.

Comment: Maybe someone was upset because you did not escape the forward slash? `^ui\/[1-9][0-9]*$`

Comment: `/` is not special in regexes, so it does not need to be escaped.

Comment: While I agree from a purity perspective, both https://regex101.com/ and https://regexr.com/ say that it is or can be problematic. fwiw, I upvoted.

Comment: Well, that depends on the language and delimiter you select. The only really problematic case is JavaScript and `/.../` regex literals (not `new RegExp`). Everything else has no issue with `/`.